# i want to insert data with function of ereg_replace gives error

Tags: php

hello i want to use a function of php (ereg_replace) for inserting data into my database but I am receiving this error saying

```
Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\spdealers\Admin Panel\Property_Insert_Page_exe.php on line 3
```

any one please ???

here is the php code : `$propertyid = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9-]", "", $_POST['propertyid'])`

Answer (score 1):

The question is already available on stackoverflow.
Please at least search on Stackoverflow, Please check the below links:-

[Function ereg_replace() is deprecated - How to clear this bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132844/function-ereg-replace-is-deprecated-how-to-clear-this-bug)

[How to solve the use of deprecated function ereg() of PHP 5.3.0 in Drupal  6.13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132912/how-to-solve-the-use-of-deprecated-function-ereg-of-php-5-3-0-in-drupal-6-13)

[Function ereg() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489151/function-ereg-is-deprecated)

switch to preg_replace() , and refer to the below link for the differences http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.posix

Comment: If my answer was of your help and solved your prob, then please accept it :)